# Django multilingual app with flatpages

Tags: django, django-flatpages

Which way is better to create a simple multilingual app with Django? I need just one or two flatpages and navigation. The problem is as follows:
- Content and navigation panel on the page should be able to change from an admin-panel.
- I need multi-language application.
I would like to hear your advice. This can be a ready-made solution (package or github project).

Comment: "Content and navigation panel on the page should be able to change from an admin-panel". Please re-read that sentence and rephrase it so people can understand.

Comment: I need packages to create dynamic navigation system and multilingual flatpages.